# Set debian Linux Timezone via command line

Tags: linux, terminal, time-zone

Is there a way i can set the current timezone via the commandline/terminal? Its for a shelle script so im looking for some, hopefully, one liner like `date -Z 'Europe/London'` (Just an example), in other words just a command to write and not anyhting todo with graphics

Is there any built in way of doing it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works on Linux Mint, Ubuntu, Debian, I think most Debian-based distros...

```
echo "America/Eastern" | sudo tee /etc/timezone
sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata
```

Where to find timezones:

- See this [Wikipedia link on the tz database](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges) for other timezones to use
- [Sources for Time Zone and Daylight Saving Time Data](http://www.twinsun.com/tz/tz-link.htm) lists more sources, like [TWiki.org Service: Date and Time Gateway - Timezone Selector](http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/xtra/tzdatepick.html)
- Looking at `/usr/share/zoneinfo/` shows zones that *should* work. Most are "Country/City" in "folder/folder" format, but if you pick a "plain" zone like MST, it may not set the daylight savings time info.

Or (as commented) use `timedatectl list-timezones` to find a zone, then `timedatectl set-timezone [timezone]`

---

If required, see this [Debian page about Time Zone Changes](https://wiki.debian.org/TimeZoneChanges). You could use the program `zic` along with changing some files, if you wanted to change the details of the time zone, like daylight savings time start & end dates, etc.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tried with `Europe/Berlin` but `dpkg-reconfigure` always sets `/etc/timezone` back to `Etc/UTC`. I have to link the zoneinfo file manually as shown in the answer by SystemCookie.

Answer (score 4):

You can change it with more than one line. Exactly two lines.

1. `mv /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.old`

and then Link your TimeZone file like this:

2. `ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europa/London /etc/localtime`

You can check with `date`

Comment: In more recent versions of systemd one can also use https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/time#Time_zone

Comment: Thanks! Also nice to know ;-) I'm not this familiar with systemd ...